# How to restrict the date field in a simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using a simple date_field in a simple_form_for and its working fine. I just need to tweek it so that it only shows dates from 12 years ago and before. I.E no one should be able to enter a date within the last 12 years.

Here is the line of code I have.

```
<%= f.date_field :birthday, start_year: Time.now.year - 100, 
          end_year: Time.now.year-12, :default => @profile.birthday %>
```

The "start_year: " and "end_year" haven't worked for me (maybe I am using them wrong?). Users can still enter invalid dates.

Does anyone know of any other things i should try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use validation in your model.

```
 validates_inclusion_of :birthday, 
   in: Date.civil(1950, 1, 1)..Date.today-14.years,
   message: "Must be between 1950 and 2000 and now"
```

For sure this is an example and you can set it to pretty much whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works great. I am just wondering if there is a way to limit the amount of dates that the user can chose from. (The user is presented with a calendar).

Comment: it would be another question, and I assume (though not claiming)  it would have something to do with javascript.